# how complicated shapes uv mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made two objects. I cant make uv mapping well.
**My objects have many faces. This is problem maybe.**
I try to put wood texture to them.
It looks very bad.
I added my objects pictures in render, solid and edit mode.

How uv mapping can fix on my objects well?
or
How can I create those objects smart way?

note; I have used array modification for object 1.
both in cycles render

Thank you for help :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are mostly flat, so the best solution seems to unwrap it with "Project from view" with viewport looking strait perpendicular to the surface. It will give you nice square map, which will allow you to use your reference directly. Maybe with some UV expanding and texture painting (with texture in stencil mode) on the most protruding parts.